# +(void)load message not sent to framework class in device runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-runtime, ios-frameworks

I've trawled through questions here on SO looking for any hints to why I'm seeing this behaviour, and nothing yet.

---

Consider a class (actually two classes exhibiting the same problem), built into a static library, wrapped in a framework bundle ([steps used](http://simplyitinc.blogspot.com/2011/04/creating-static-framework-in-xcode-4.html)). They inherit from Foundation framework [class clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html) (`NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray`).

The use of these classes relies on some static variables being initialised before a static function (*not class method!*) is used to allocate and initialise an instance (a kind of factory helper function I guess?).

When an iOS app project links to that framework there is a difference the Objective-C runtime class loading behaviour between the Simulator and the Device.

Specifically, on a device (iPhone 4, iOS 4.3.3) when the app is loaded these classes do not get a `+load` message, and the static vars do not initialize, therefore the static factory method fails. On the Simulator, the messages are sent, and all works as intended. Could it be a problem with the Device runtime having a

My question is, can my framework be configured differently to ensure the `+load` messages are sent? Or have I run into a bug with static library/framework class loading in iOS?

---

The classes are from the [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) library ([`JKArray`](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/master/JSONKit.m#L613), [`JKDictionary`](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/master/JSONKit.m#L833)).

An example project that illustrates this problem is here – https://github.com/ohhorob/JSONKit-in-framework-demo

---

EDIT: As per @bbum's suggestion, I've verified that the `JKDictionary` and `JKArray` classes are in fact loaded and available while the application is running. The `DeviceBroken` branch on the GitHub project is updated with the verification used.

I filed a bugreport (#9461567) with Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+load` methods are not called because you did not actually create a **static library** but a ***Relocatable Object File* bundle**. If you create the static framework with either [make-fmwk](https://github.com/defagos/make-fmwk) or the [iOS Universal Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) template then the load methods will be called as expected.

Comment: Can you expand this answer by pointing to some official Apple documentation that explains the difference?  When I read "Relocatable Object File bundle", I see either "Framework" (more likely) or "dynamic shared library".  In either case, `+load` would still be called when either is loaded (in the context of what we are discussing, a framework and dynamic shared library are essentially same thing).

Comment: Also, I just realized that the solution to the OP's problem was to move everything to a `__attribute__((constructor))` qualified function.  Why would this work in a "Relocatable Object File bundle" but `+load` would not?

Comment: *Relocatable Object File* just means a `.o` file whose type is `MH_OBJECT`. The best documentation you can find about it is probably the [macho-o/loader.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.9.59/osfmk/mach-o/loader.h) header file. Now, **why** `+load` doesn't work in a relocatable object file is a mystery, since the load methods actually end up in the final executable binary.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if I'm missing something, but I don't think the (top-level) answer is really an explanation for why the problem is happing.  Static libraries are nothing more than a bunch of `.o` files grouped together- really nothing more than a `tar` like format for `.o` files, which you create / manipulate with `ar`.  Try `size /usr/lib/libiodbc.a`, as an example.  The steps referenced by the OP look like they create a `.Framework`, which is just a fancy way of bundling a dynamic shared library.  Very weird problem.

Answer (score 3):

Odd;  I'd do an `NSLog(@"klassy klass %@", [MysteryClass class]);` and make sure the classes are actually loaded (but see below -- this may "fix" the problem).

If they are, then this is a bug in the DYLD loader and please file it.

If not, then it is likely that the linker is stripping the class(es) because nothing references them directly.  Try adding `[MysteryClass class]` in the app's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method (doesn't really matter where or, even, if it gets executed... but that'll be an obvious spot).

Also, I'd suggest not using `+load` and, instead, writing a constructor function.  I.e.:

```
__attribute__((constructor))
static void initLibrary()
{
    ....
}
```

If this is a linker issue, that may or may not fix the problem.  It is, however, much clearer as to your intentions than the rather magical `+load` method.

Comment: Using the suggested `NSLog()` I verified that the `JKDictionary` class is loaded. I also verified that `+load` is being called on my normal (non-library/framework) classes of the app. I'll file it as a bug!

Comment: If you added the +load outside of the static lib, that might have been enough to force it to load.... use `NSClassFromString()` to avoid that.

Comment: I added a `+load` to the app delegate to confirm that it does get that  message. Is that what you're referring to about _"added the +load outside of the static lib"_? Changing the `NSLog()` to use the `NSClassFromString()` also confirms that the `JKDictionary` class is available when the app delegate finishes launching.

Comment: Yah-- my thinking was that the linker was potentially not linking everything if there were no references to the symbol.  Doesn't sound like that is the case.  Sounds just busted. :)

Comment: The author of [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) did actually provide a patch, using a constructor to do that initialisation, and it's working well. Hopefully he'll bring that into the project for a permanent workaround of this issue.

Comment: Did you add the -ObjC linker flag to the linking of the app w/the library?

Comment: I've tried `-ObjC` and `-all_load`, even `-force_load WrapperLib`, but none have resulted in `+load` messages going to the framework classes

Comment: For the record, I suggested the `__attribute((constructor))` workaround to @ohhorob as well (which included the code/logic that was supposed to be executed in `+load`), and he [commented](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/pull/23#issuecomment-1198341) that the `__attribute((constructor))` function was getting called.  I just suggested in his bug report to try the `-ObjC -all_load` flags, but it looks like that was tried and didn't work.  IMHO, this would seem to be some kind of bug in the compiler tool chain when dealing with static libs.